# R kableExtra latex: Add linebreaks to rotated header row

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kableextra

I'm trying to produce table to a Latex-pdf document. I'm using kableExtra and knitr in R.

I have a table that has long column names. When I rotate the header row by 90 degrees linebreaks won't work. Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve both rotated row and linebreaks?

My example is the same as in [Hao's Best Practice for newline in Latex table](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf), but I added piped *row_spec* to the end of the code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
<<global_options, echo=FALSE>>=
library(kableExtra)
library("dplyr")
dt_lb <- data.frame(
  Item = c("Hello\nWorld", "This\nis a cat"),
  Value = c(10, 100)
)
dt_lb %>%
  mutate_all(linebreak) %>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = T, escape = F,
        col.names = linebreak(c("Item\n(Name)", "Value\n(Number)"))) %>%
  row_spec(0, angle = 90, align='l', monospace=T)

@

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this, but the *[l]* tags hint that there's something else wrong with the tags as well:

[image]

On StackExchange TEX I found a question about rotation and linebreaks, this is what I'm trying achieve: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/big-table-with-rotated-column-labels-using-booktabs

Comment: Edited my example to include the Latex part.

Comment: The problem seems to Latex-related not R-related, so this post is on the wrong forum or should even be deleted. I'm sorry to have bothered you with this one I really did try to do research beforehand. Problem was missing call \usepackage{makecell}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latex package makecell was missing.

Hao pointed out that Page 3 of this manual lists some of the necessary Latex packages: haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tableHTML`:

```
library(tableHTML)
```

Replace the new line character `"\n"` with the `HTML` tag `<br>`:

```
headers <- c("Item\n(Name)", "Value\n(Number)") %>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = "\\n", replacement = "<br>")
```

Create a `tableHTML` object and rotate the headers using `add_css_header()`:

```
dt_lb %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            headers = headers,
            escape = FALSE,
            widths = c(100, 100),
            theme = 'scientific') %>%
  add_css_header(css = list(c('transform', 'height', 'text-align'), 
                            c('rotate(-45deg)', '70px', 'center')),
                 headers = 1:2)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Note: you can add more css or default themes. Check out the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html) for more details:

If you want to create a `pdf` document, you could use `RMarkdown`:

````
---
title: "tableHTML2pdf"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
\

```{r}

library(tableHTML)

dt_lb <- data.frame(
  Item = c("Hello\nWorld", "This\nis a cat"),
  Value = c(10, 100)
)

headers <- c("Item\n(Name)", "Value\n(Number)") %>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = "\\n", replacement = "<br>")


dt_lb %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            headers = headers,
            escape = FALSE,
            widths = c(100, 100),
            theme = 'scientific') %>%
  add_css_header(css = list(c('transform', 'height', 'text-align'), 
                            c('rotate(-45deg)', '70px', 'center')),
                 headers = 1:2)
```

\
````

It will then create an `HTML` file. This file can then be converted to `PDF` using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

Comment: I'm trying to produce pdf document with Latex and R, but I see now I could have mentioned it more clearly in the text. I guess tableHTML doesn't help with that?

Comment: I have a long report (written in Latex), this table is only a small part of it. Changing from Latex to HTML is not really an option at this point, even though I'd probably by happier with RMarkdown or HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably rendered your rmarkdown document into HTML... In the rmarkdown yaml header, does it say `html_document` right now? If so, you can try to change it to `pdf_document`.....

I rendered a `pdf_document` with exactly the same code and I think I got what you were looking for...

[image]

````
---
title: "Table Sample"
output: pdf_document
---

``` {r, include = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)

library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
dt_lb <- data.frame(
  Item = c("Hello\nWorld", "This\nis a cat"),
  Value = c(10, 100)
)
dt_lb %>%
  mutate_all(linebreak) %>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = T, escape = F,
    col.names = linebreak(c("Item\n(Name)", "Value\n(Number)"), align = "c")) %>%
 row_spec(0, angle = 90)
```
````

Comment: I'm writing Latex document, not HTML or R Markdown. They are different things. I really appreciate the help, but I just can't convert to HTML with my report.

Comment: @Sushi I'm not using sweave but can you try to load the latex packages on Page 3 of this manual http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Comment: makecell package from that list was missing.